# Compilation error "Error: Missing \begin{document}."

Tags: errors

I declared my document in this manner and have been working successfully with it for a while.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibtotoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[]{textcomp}
\usepackage[]{booktabs}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor = black, citecolor = black, filecolor = black, urlcolor = blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[]{acronym}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
text...
\end{document}
```

But I think either since trying to use \textsubscript in the acronym section or working on the labels for some graphics I receive:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
\protect 
l.43 ...rfl\IeC {\"a}chenzustandsdichteverteilung}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                  
l.43 ...rfl\IeC {\"a}chenzustandsdichteverteilung}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Extra \endcsname.
\AC@newacro ...fter \gdef \csname fn@#1\endcsname 
{{#2}{#3}}
l.43 ...rfl\IeC {\"a}chenzustandsdichteverteilung}
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
\protect 
l.44 ...nimale Oberfl\IeC {\"a}chenzustandsdichte}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
```

The extra and missing endcsname repeat on and on. And since I started my document with \begin{document}, I'm not sure how to fix this.
Would greatly appreciate your help and input

Hi and thanks for your quick responses. I cleaned up my code and removed all "Umlaute" from the labels. Are there other places where I shouldn't use them? The check for "flächenzustandsdichteverteilung" showed that it was once in my acronym section and once in the text. Both are gone. Now the compiler runs a litte longer but unfotunately still shows the same error.

Comment: Hi and welcome, does the above code give any errors? Works fine on my machine. Is your document `latin1`encoded? Comment out packages `ucs` and `inputenc` and add `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`.

Comment: Do not use umlauts in labels, it is bad. Really reallt bad.

Comment: It compiles fine on my machine too. Btw, why do you load `wrapfig`, `hyperref` and `url` twice?

Comment: Obviously you used `flächenzustandsdichteverteilung` somewhere where shouldn't have done it. So search in your code for suspects.

Comment: You shouldn't use `geometry` with `scrreport`, by the way. And if your document is UTF8 encoded, use `utf8` rather than `utf8x` if you are using a language which allows it.

Comment: @patrice It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: @cfr You shouldn't use geometry if you want to let `typearea` work for you. If you have special margin specifications, `geomtry` is just fine.

Comment: @patrice make sure to delete the aux file (and other auxiliary files).

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the problem fixed: The problem was that my document used ISO-8859-x codification, but ShareLaTeX only supports utf8.
So I took out
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
and replaced it by
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
Thanks a lot again for your support